# Find the maximum and minimum element in an array

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, array-algorithms

**In this question i can't find the error everything seems correct to me, i am sorting the array using Quick Sort but the sorting algorithm is not working , so that i can find the max and min**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void swap(int *a, int *b){
    int t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}

int partition(vector<int> arr ,int low, int high){
    int pivot = arr[high];
    int i = low-1;
    for (int j=low; j<=high; j++){
        if(arr[j]<pivot){
            i++;
            swap(&arr[i],&arr[j]);
        }
    }
    swap(&arr[i+1],&arr[high]);
    return (i+1);
}

void quickSort(vector<int> arr, int low, int high){
    if(low<high){
        int pi = partition(arr,low,high);
        quickSort(arr,low,pi-1);
        quickSort(arr,pi+1,high);
    }
}


int main()
{
    vector<int> arr = {5,2,3,4,1};
    int arr_size = arr.size();
    quickSort(arr,0,arr_size-1);
    cout<<"The minimum and maximum array is \n";
    cout<<arr[0]<<" "<<arr[arr_size-1];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through your code with the debugger line by line?

Comment: If your function takes the vector by value, any changes will not be seen by the caller.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ when i am checking with debugger pivot = 0 in the function partition ,pls help me

Comment: @interjay how do i call by reference any example.

Comment: You make the parameter `vector<int> &arr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `quicksort()` and `partition()`:

```cpp
int partition(vector<int> arr ,int low, int high){
    int pivot = arr[high];
    int i = low-1;
    for (int j=low; j<=high; j++){
        if(arr[j]<pivot){
            i++;
            swap(&arr[i],&arr[j]);
        }
    }
    swap(&arr[i+1],&arr[high]);
    return (i+1);
}
void quickSort(vector<int> arr, int low, int high){
    if(low<high){
        int pi = partition(arr,low,high);
        quickSort(arr,low,pi-1);
        quickSort(arr,pi+1,high);
    }
}
```

You pass `vector<int> arr` by value, which means the compiler will make a copy of `arr`, not changing the actual value of `arr`.

You have to pass by reference instead:

```cpp
int partition(vector<int> &arr ,int low, int high){
    int pivot = arr[high];
    int i = low-1;
    for (int j=low; j<=high; j++){
        if(arr[j]<pivot){
            i++;
            swap(&arr[i],&arr[j]);
        }
    }
    swap(&arr[i+1],&arr[high]);
    return (i+1);
}
void quickSort(vector<int> &arr, int low, int high){
    if(low<high){
        int pi = partition(arr,low,high);
        quickSort(arr,low,pi-1);
        quickSort(arr,pi+1,high);
    }
}
```

But, you can also use `std::sort` instead. In `main()`:

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> arr = {5,2,3,4,1};
    int arr_size = (int)arr.size();
    std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
    std::cout<<"The minimum and maximum array is \n";
    std::cout<<arr[0]<<" "<<arr[arr_size-1];

    return 0;
}
```

But the "sorting" solution, in general, is inefficient. You should use `std::minmax_element` instead:

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> arr = {5,2,3,4,1};
    auto result = std::minmax_element(arr.begin(), arr.end());
    std::cout<<"The minimum and maximum array is \n";
    std::cout<< *result.first <<' '<< *result.second;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or use `std::minmax_element`.